# Incorporate variables into bash code line

Tags: bash, variables, awk

Well maybe this is not the best title; but it's hard to convey my intention only in short title.

I've a line here:

```
2   118610455   P2_PM_2_5034    T   <DUP:TANDEM>    40  .   END=118610566;SVLEN=110;SVTYPE=TDUP;CIPOS=-100,55;CIEND=-56,100;IMPRECISE;DBVARID=esv7540;VALIDATED;VALMETHOD=CGH;SVMETHOD=RP
```

Basically I would like to convert it into:

```
2 118610455 118610566
```

So major problem is to grep this `118610566` from the 8th column.

I know how to grep this number:

```
$c=`cat line|awk '{print $8}'|sed 's/;/\t/g'|awk '{print $1}'|sed 's/\END=//g'`
```

but my question is then how I can incorporate this variable into another bash line:

```
what_i_want=`cat line|awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$c}'`
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little string manipulation you can get it in one go.

```
what_i_want=$(awk '{sub(/^END=/,"",$8); sub(/;.*$/,"",$8); print $1,$2,$8}' line)
```

Some explanation:

`sub(a,b,c)` searches for pattern `a` in variable `c` and replaces it with `b`, storing the modified string back into `c`. Patterns are written within `//`.

`^` is the beginning of the string, `$` is the end, `.` is anything, and `*` means zero or more of the preceding pattern.  So in our case:

`sub(/^END=/,"",$8);` matches `END=` at the beginning (`^`) of the string and replaces it with `""`, nothing, essentially deleting it.

`sub(/;.*$/,"",$8);` takes everything (`.*`) from `;` to the end (`$`) and deletes it.  Note that in awk, as with most regex engines, `*` is *greedy*, which means it takes the longest match it can get, so we know this will get the first `;`.

And all we are left with is the number you want.

Comment: thx works well...but can you explain a bit about sub(/;.*/,"",$8) ? I know here to truncate the part after ; right? but I don't understand what . and * means here.

Answer (score 3):

May be this can help -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat tmp
2   118610455   P2_PM_2_5034    T   <DUP:TANDEM>    40  .   END=118610566;SVLEN=110;SVTYPE=TDUP;CIPOS=-100,55;CIEND=-56,100;IMPRECISE;DBVARID=esv7540;VALIDATED;VALMETHOD=CGH;SVMETHOD=RP

[jaypal:~/Temp] var=$(awk -v FS="[ ;=]" '{print $1,$4,$24}' tmp)

[jaypal:~/Temp] echo $var
2 118610455 118610566
```

`FS` is `awk's` built-in variable. It is defaulted to a space or a tab. Since your line as more than one delimiter setting the `FS` to a character class helps in splitting the line for each de-limiter. The character class we have defined here is either a `space`, `semi-colon` or `equal`.

Might feel a little odd but I use this as a my debugging tool for identifying columns when I happen to parse a line with more than 1 delimiters. This is what I had got from your line -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v FS="[ ;=]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "$"i" is "$i}' tmp
$1 is 2
$2 is 
$3 is 
$4 is 118610455
$5 is 
$6 is 
$7 is P2_PM_2_5034
$8 is 
$9 is 
$10 is 
$11 is T
$12 is 
$13 is 
$14 is <DUP:TANDEM>
$15 is 
$16 is 
$17 is 
$18 is 40
$19 is 
$20 is .
$21 is 
$22 is 
$23 is END
$24 is 118610566
$25 is SVLEN
$26 is 110
$27 is SVTYPE
$28 is TDUP
$29 is CIPOS
$30 is -100,55
$31 is CIEND
$32 is -56,100
$33 is IMPRECISE
$34 is DBVARID
$35 is esv7540
$36 is VALIDATED
$37 is VALMETHOD
$38 is CGH
$39 is SVMETHOD
$40 is RP
```

You can also use a simple `substr` built-in function of `awk` in the following manner -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '{print $1,$2,$8=substr($8,5,9)}' tmp
2 118610455 118610566
```

Comment: thx but can you explain about FS="[;=]" a bit? I don't know why 11861045 becomes the 4th column.

Answer (score 0):

If your "columns" are always separated by whitespace, then you don't need to use subshells and awk, you can do this directly in shell:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ read one two three four five junk <<< "2   118610455   P2_PM_2_5034    T   <DUP:TANDEM>    40  .   END=118610566;SVLEN=110;SVTYPE=TDUP;CIPOS=-100,55;CIEND=-56,100;IMPRECISE;DBVARID=esv7540;VALIDATED;VALMETHOD=CGH;SVMETHOD=RP"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo "$five"
<DUP:TANDEM>
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo "$junk"
40 . END=118610566;SVLEN=110;SVTYPE=TDUP;CIPOS=-100,55;CIEND=-56,100;IMPRECISE;DBVARID=esv7540;VALIDATED;VALMETHOD=CGH;SVMETHOD=RP
```

The last variable specified on your `read` line gets "everything else".

Also. if you're handling multiple lines like this, you can run it in a loop:

```
cat /path/to/inputfile | while read one two three four five junk; do
  echo "$one - $two - $five"
done
```

Salt to taste.